# How to name fields using Dynamic Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dynamic, dynamic-linq

I have a huge query that is being made dynamically, but I want the select statement to not output the column names, buut custom values.  FOr example, if I am doing a normal Linq query, I can do something like this:

```
var v = from p in db.items select new { name = p.item_name, price = p.item_price };
```

which will give me the nice '.name' and '.price' accessors

but if I am using Dyanmic Linq, I can do this:

```
var v = db.items.Select("new (item_name,item_price)");
```

works fine, but

```
var v = db.items.Select("new (name=item_name,price=item_price)");
```

I get an error:
*"No property or field 'name' exists in type 'item'"*

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, figured it out, this wis what was needed:

```
var v = db.items.Select("new (item_name as name,item_price as price)");
```

Comment: how can you access to those fields? v.name? :s

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this.

```
var v = db.items.Select("new(it[\"item_name\"]  as name,it[\"item_price\"] as price)");
```